# Index changing before interval is set

Tags: javascript, for-loop, setinterval

I have the following function in a for-loop:

```
loops.push(setInterval(function(){
    showNext(i);
}, 5000));
```

`i` is the index of the for-loop. A problem arises when the push function is run, however. `i` is always set to the last index of the for-loop because by the time the interval function is called, the for-loop has finished executing.

How can I make the interval receive the index of the for-loop that it is on **now**, rather than have it set to the last index of the for-loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding a closure. Like this:

```
for(var i=0; i<n; i++){
  (function(i){
      loops.push(setInterval(function(){
         showNext(i);
      }, 5000));
  })(i);
}
```

This way, the internal `i` is different to the external one. This is the same but more understandable:

```
for(var i=0; i<n; i++){
  (function(x){
      loops.push(setInterval(function(){
         showNext(x);
      }, 5000));
  })(i);
}
```

In this way, there's a different `x` per loop cycle. As it's no longer shared, it doesn't get overwritten.

Cheers, from La Paz, Bolivia

Comment: Btw, I think you meant `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` :)

Comment: No it's a carousel of images, so I want it to be a timer.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind `i` as an argument to your function:

```
loops.push(setInterval(showNext.bind(this, i), 5000));
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f7Snq/)**</kbd>

<sub><sup>*Are you sure by using **setInterval** instead of **setTimeout**?*</sup></sub>

Comment: Yeah I'm sure I want to use setInterval. I'm looping a carousel of images.

Answer (score 0):

Use ***[Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)*** is much simple:

```
// the first parameter of bind is not important in this case.
loops.push(setInterval(showNext.bind(this, i), 5000));
```

Note `.bind` need a Polyfill for old browsers.